# User Interaction Enabled Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I am writing a Javascript application and am going to wrap it in a native iOS application. I would like to block user interaction on the UIWebView containing the JS app for a second or two following an event.

Normally I would use the self.webView.userinteractionenabled = NO but the event is triggered in Javascript. How can I block the user from interacting with the web view?

Guessing return false on a touch event of some sort? It's scrolling that I want to block.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the event occurs in your Javascript code you can send a message to the native wrapper by using the following method:

Set up the following UIWebViewDelegate method (don't forget to set the delegate for the UIWebView):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
   NSURL *url = [request URL];
   if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"block"]) {
      // do the your blocking code here
      return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}
```

Now when your event happens, call the delegate method from your javascript code:

```
window.location.href = "block://";
```

Comment: excellent, I didn't think communicating like that was possible! You just made my life much easier